# Loading global variable in function in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, for-loop, crash

At the bottom of my post is the code. This script runs on is own. I want to use it to make an array of information about plugins(each plugin has it's own folder). The file is stored next to a folder called: plugins. This folder contains the following folders:

1. File_manager
2. mySQL-Tools
3. network tracker
4. PHP-Toolbox
5. Super-variables
6. Theme-incarnate

When I run the script I get the folowing result:

```
+------------------------------------+
Index = 0
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 0
+------------------------------------+
Index = 1
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 0
+------------------------------------+
Index = 2
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 0
+------------------------------------+
Index = 3
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 0
+------------------------------------+
Index = 4
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 1
+------------------------------------+
Index = 5
Dir = ./plugins/File_manager
Value = 1
Hello worldHello world2
```

The result I posted above here isn't actually code. But this way you can see it better (otherwise it would be seen as one big line of text).

As you can see It doesn't complete the for loop and omits what's after the for loop. And I figured out it was because of this line `global $temp, $Dir, $n_index;`. Which is in the `file_status()` function. What's weird is that the code does work until it repeats the loop. So that would mean that the script crashes after it is crashed? Please help. If someone would need to run the code to be able to help me I could provide a link to the file.

```
<?php
//Scan the "plugins" directory for folders but omit the "./" and "../" folder
$array = array_diff( scandir("plugins"), array(".", "..") );

$Plugins_info=array();
for($n=2; $n<=count($array)+1; $n++){
    //create temporary array
    $temp=array();

    //define directory of the plugin
    $Dir="./plugins/".$array[$n];

    //Set the index value of the array to 0
    $n_index=0;
    //Function that will put inormation about the files in the array
    function file_status($filename){
        global $temp, $Dir, $n_index;
        echo "+------------------------------------+<br />";
        echo "Index = ".$n_index."<br/>";
        echo "Dir = ".$Dir."<br/>";
        if (file_exists($Dir."/".$filename))$temp[$n_index++]=1;
        else $temp[$n_index++]=0;
        echo "Value = ".$temp[$n_index-1]."<br/>";
    }
    $files=array("index.php", "Install.php", "update.php", "uninstall.php", "load.php", "settings.php");
    foreach($files as $value){
        file_status($value);
    }
    echo "Hello world";
    //Change the plugin name to an array that holds all the plugin information
    $Plugins_info[$n-2]=$temp;
    echo "Hello world2";
}
echo "Hello world3";
//Output the whole array (each plugin separated by a fancy line)
foreach($Plugins_info as $Temp_array){
    echo "+------------------------------------+<br />";
    foreach($Temp_array as $Temp_value){
        echo "[".$Temp_value."]<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If someone can come up with a better version of my code that bypasses this error that's of course also okay.

Comment: For a start, you can't define a named function inside of a for loop. move that out to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on error reporting!!!

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You are getting a`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_status() (previously declared in  bla bla in bla line bla` because your function definition is in the loop.

The loop is only executing once and then a second time up to the point where you try and redefine the function.

Move the function `file_status()` outside of any loops.

Comment: Tnx, I wil try that. And post the results.